# How do you use a FlatList inside a ScrollView in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use a flatlist to to display posts from a database, but the flatlist is only taking half the screen and the other 2 containers are taking up roughly half the screen as well, currently when I scroll on the flatlist, the posts are just being displayed in the bottom half of the screen (as expected), but I want the whole page to scroll, so the posts can be seen on a full screen so they're easier to read.

Here is a simplified version of my layout...

```
<View>
  <View>
    // some content
  </View>
  <View>
    // some content
  </View>
  <FlatList
    // posts displayed from a database
  />
</View>
```

Is there a way to keep the Flatlist component but allow the whole screen to slide up when first scrolling  until the FlatList reaches the top of the page, and then it starts scrolling through the FlatList?

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't render `FlatList` inside a `ScrollView` because of the performance issue. what you can do is define a `FlatList` as the main container in your component and then pass all other views that you want to display above `FlatList` to the [ListHeaderComponent](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent) prop of `FlatList`

```js
  <FlatList
    ListHeaderComponent={
      <View>
        // some content
      </View>
      <View>
        // some content
      </View>
    }
    data={someDataArray}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <SomeItem />
    )}
    keyExtractor={(data) => data.id}
  />
```

This way your whole screen would be scrollable

Answer (score 1):

Your current simplified layout:

```
<View>
    <View>
        // some content
    </View>
    <View>
        // some content
    </View>
    <FlatList
      // posts displayed from a database
    />
</View>
```

To allow the entire screen, not just the FlatList, to scroll you can use the [ListHeaderComponent](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent) property:

```
<View>
    <FlatList
        ListHeaderComponent={
            <View>
                // some content
            </View>
            <View>
                // some content
            </View>        
        }
      // other FlatList properties to render your posts 
    />
</View>
```

And as you may expect, you can also render components underneath the list of posts using the [ListFooterComponent](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listfootercomponent):

```
<View>
    <FlatList
        ListHeaderComponent={
            <View>
                // some header content
            </View>
        }
        ListFooterComponent={
            <View>
                // some footer content
            </View>        
        }
      // other FlatList properties to render your posts 
    />
</View>
```